# suppress `unused` warning by file or package

Tags: java, eclipse

I am linking in a third-party Java package that has many "unused" warnings. I prefer not to edit third-party source code with @SuppressWarnings. Is there a way to set Eclipse so that unused warnings are suppressed for entire packages or entire files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Errors/Warnings

unused specifically is under Unnecessary Code

I'm not sure if you can disable it per-package, my guess is you'd need a (maybe non-existent) plugin to do that.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest building third-party sources in a separate project. That way you can control warning levels specifically for the third-party sources, and it also keeps your own code separate from the third-party code, which is a good separation pattern to use.

Answer (score 0):

Warnings for entire `files` can be suppressed by placing `@SuppressWarnings("all")` near the top of the file but after the `package` statement and `import` statements.

Placing that annotation above the package statement results in a confusing error message. Placing it after `package` but before the `import` statements results in an somewhat more helpful error message that states "misplaced construct(s)" in Eclipse Neon.